# How to build HTML5 skill in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am looking for a documentation or Github to build a HTML 5 (non gaming) skill in Alexa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web API for Games is currently the *only* Alexa Skills Kit API that exposes HTML5 on compatible devices and the docs for that say specifically it's only approved for games.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/web-api-for-games/understand-alexa-web-api-for-games.html#requirements-for-the-skill-and-web-app

Comment: I am looking at the requirements section, but I can not find any restriction which would state that the app has to be a game. Did they change it?

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/web-api-for-games/alexa-games-build-your-webapp.html. "Note: Your HTML application must be a game. Other types of apps can't use the Alexa Web API for Games."